How to estimate the integral $\displaystyle\int |v|^\alpha|Sv| $?
Let $n\geq3$ and $1\leq\alpha<2^*-1\ \ \left(2^*=\displaystyle\frac{2n}{n-2}\right)$. Let $p=\alpha(2^*)'$. Define the operator
\begin{align*}
S:\ L^2\big((0,T),L^p(\Omega)\big)&\longrightarrow L^2\big((0,T),L^p(\Omega)\big)
\\ v&\longmapsto Sv
\end{align*}
where $Sv$ is the solution of the nonlinear heat equation $u_t-\Delta u=u^\alpha$ with Dirichlet boundary condition.
I want to estimate the integral
$$\int\limits_\Omega |v(t)|^\alpha\,|Sv(t)| $$ so that it express something involves the terms $\|v(t)\|_p^2$ and $\|Sv(t)\|_{H^1_0}^2$. $\Big($I need these terms because I need to take the integral on $[0,T]$ after estimating it since my goal is to estimate the norms $\|v\|_{L^2(0,T;L^p)}$ and $\|Sv\|_{L^2(0,T;H^1_0)} \Big)$.
Here is my attempt : by Holder inequality,
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\Omega |v(t)|^\alpha\,|Sv(t)| &\leq \big\|v(t)^\alpha\big\|_{(2^*)'}\big\|Sv(t)\big\|_{2^*}
\\ &=\big\|v(t)\big\|_{\alpha (2^*)'}^\alpha\big\|Sv(t)\big\|_{2^*}
\\ &\leq \big\|v(t)\big\|_{\alpha (2^*)'}^{2\alpha}+\big\|Sv(t)\big\|_{2^*}^2
\\ &\leq \big\|v(t)\big\|_{p}^{2\alpha}+C_S\big\|Sv(t)\big\|_{H^1_0}^2
\end{align}
where $C_S$ is from the Sobolev embedding. However, this is not what I actually want, since I couldn't make the terms $\|v\|_{L^2(0,T;L^p)}$ appear with this estimate, where I struggle in the term
$$\int\limits_0^T\big\|v(t)\big\|_p^{2\alpha}dt. $$
Specificularly, if
$$\|v\|_{L^2(0,T;L^p)}^2=\int\limits_0^T\big\|v(t)\big\|_p^2\,dt\leq C $$
for some $C>0$, how can I estimate the precede integral ? Thanks.
